# JavaScript function is displaying function name as undefined when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am testing how to change text and CSS elements using Javascript

I have three buttons in my HTML, only one so far that I am using (Change Title).  I would like to change the H1 Text when I click the button.

Using my current coding, when I click the button nothing happens and I get the following displayed in the web developer tools console:

*ReferenceError: changeTitle is not defined [Learn More]  Index.html:1:1

Onclick  file:///D:/Google%20Drive/Programming/EDX/Introduction%20to%20JavaScript/Module_1/index.html:1:1*

***Questions:***

1. Can someone please help me understand why the browser says that the changeTitle function is not defined when I believe I have defined it in the external JS file.
2. Am I able to use the onclick method?? in the   tag element so that I do not have to use buttons?

Please find snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
    title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

header > h1 {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #A47F1A;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: dashed 5px #A47F1A;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #3B2E2A
}

 .nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3B2E2A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding: 20px 0 20px 0;*/
}

 .nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding: 0 25px;*/
}

 .nav li a {
  color: #FEF1E0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #3B2E2A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content > p {
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test JS Usage</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1 class="head-title">
            Pirate Verbal Diahorrea
         </h1>
         <nav>
            <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Title</button>
            <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Para1 colour</button>
            <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Header Colour</button>
         </nav>
         <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Change Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Change Para1 colour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Change Header Colour</a></li>
         </ul>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
         <p class="para1">
            Ahoy league cutlass Sail ho grapple brig cable Chain Shot topgallant rutters grog keel run a shot across the bow squiffy execution dock chandler ballast heave to come about weigh anchor. Bowsprit Yellow Jack lugsail warp gally piracy strike colors flogging come about avast fluke Sea Legs parrel black spot hempen halter run a shot across the bow American Main crow's nest red ensign cable. Gally jolly boat long clothes quarterdeck fluke league bilge water dance the hempen jig interloper jib scourge of the seven seas swab haul wind Chain Shot draught rope's end belay reef Yellow Jack Buccaneer. Nelsons folly topsail Cat o'nine tails hail-shot scuttle scourge of the seven seas loaded to the gunwalls carouser Sail ho fluke bowsprit lateen sail gabion yard provost hands mutiny cog belay blow the man down. Draught hornswaggle barkadeer jib interloper fore marooned sloop lad scurvy hardtack nipperkin grapple piracy take a caulk capstan lateen sail yard scuppers coxswain. 
         </p>
         <p class="para2">
            Handsomely clap of thunder flogging pillage Jack Tar wherry pirate plunder keel quarter red ensign hands draught league Shiver me timbers smartly swab fathom haul wind hail-shot. Bilge rat landlubber or just lubber crack Jennys tea cup rum wherry Buccaneer heave to spike bilge water avast red ensign piracy tack mutiny chase guns shrouds cackle fruit booty main sheet quarter. Barque six pounders scuttle shrouds bilged on her anchor tender rigging Admiral of the Black gabion spike Arr belay sloop me rope's end lee black spot weigh anchor yo-ho-ho holystone. Holystone overhaul walk the plank schooner to go on account swab yard parley boom plunder lateen sail ho draught tack deadlights gunwalls parrel smartly maroon dance the hempen jig. Dance the hempen jig Chain Shot Cat o'nine tails skysail code of conduct case shot Letter of Marque stern run a shot across the bow jolly boat booty jack six pounders pink barkadeer Nelsons folly mutiny Sink me belay heave to. 
         </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any variables you define inside your document ready handler will not be accessible from outside that handler function. This includes any functions you define inside. You need to learn about **scope** in Javascript.

Comment: On the other hand, you could also learn about adding event listeners to your html elements which will also solve the problem. So either you define `changeTitle` outside the `document.ready` function, or you do something like `$('button').on('click', changeTitle)` inside the `document.ready` function

Comment: @Icepickle It will not solve the problem as long as OP doesn't understand how to make the handler function available to the event.

Comment: @connexo don't worry, I agree with you that he should learn scope, but I think that one should rather use best practices, which doesn't include mixing ui and event listeners, but that should rather be done by attaching event handlers (and I was still updating my comment :))

Comment: Thanks @connexo I will read up on Scope

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle I will also read up on event listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Purpose of `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* handling code for the event document.ready */ })
```

First of all you need to understand the purpose of this document.ready handler. When your page loads, your javascripts cannot be certain as of what parts of the DOM are already available. document.ready triggers when the DOM is complete so you can start selecting elements either using jQuery or `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`.

### Making stuff globally available

If you want to define functions that are globally available you do not do this inside another function, but if you insist, you need to explicitly attach the function to the global object (which, in a browser, is the `window` object):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.changeTitle = function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
    title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
  };
});
```

The better way to do this would be to define the function outside the handler:

```
function changeTitle() {
  var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
  title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
};
```

which *implicitly* attaches it to the global object and makes it accessible from anywhere by just calling it using `changeTitle()`.

### Adding the function to handle button clicks - the proper way

To give you a sense of how you do attach event handlers to elements, here comes the `document.ready` handler back into play:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('nav button').forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', changeTitle);
  })
});
```

If you're already using jQuery, this can be simplified to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav button').on('click', changeTitle);
});
```

### Chaining makes code shorter

```
var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
```

can be shortened to

```
document.querySelector(".head-title").innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
```

Comment: Thanks Mate.  I appreciate your help.  I am very new to this and am trying to teach myself.  Sometimes I do not know the right words to search for when looking up answers to issues I encounter.

Comment: You're welcome. We all have started at some point and I sincerely hope you're enjoying the trip. I promise it gets increasingly interesting the longer it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please help me understand why the browser says that the
>   changeTitle function is not defined when I believe I have defined it
>   in the external JS file.

For method invocation from **inline onclick** to work, that method needs to be defined globally. And your **`changeTitle` method is local to `document.ready`** event handler.

If you want to define the `changeTitle` function in document.ready, you can use jquery's `click`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
    title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
  };

  $( "button" ).click( changeTitle );

});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
    title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
  };
  
  $( "button" ).click( changeTitle );

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

header > h1 {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #A47F1A;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: dashed 5px #A47F1A;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #3B2E2A
}

 .nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3B2E2A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding: 20px 0 20px 0;*/
}

 .nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding: 0 25px;*/
}

 .nav li a {
  color: #FEF1E0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #3B2E2A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content > p {
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test JS Usage</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1 class="head-title">
   Pirate Verbal Diahorrea
  </h1>
  <nav>
   <button>Change Title</button>
   <button>Change Para1 colour</button>
   <button>Change Header Colour</button>
  </nav>
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Change Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Change Para1 colour</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Change Header Colour</a></li>
  </ul>
  
 </header>
 <div class="content">
  <p class="para1">
   Ahoy league cutlass Sail ho grapple brig cable Chain Shot topgallant rutters grog keel run a shot across the bow squiffy execution dock chandler ballast heave to come about weigh anchor. Bowsprit Yellow Jack lugsail warp gally piracy strike colors flogging come about avast fluke Sea Legs parrel black spot hempen halter run a shot across the bow American Main crow's nest red ensign cable. Gally jolly boat long clothes quarterdeck fluke league bilge water dance the hempen jig interloper jib scourge of the seven seas swab haul wind Chain Shot draught rope's end belay reef Yellow Jack Buccaneer. Nelsons folly topsail Cat o'nine tails hail-shot scuttle scourge of the seven seas loaded to the gunwalls carouser Sail ho fluke bowsprit lateen sail gabion yard provost hands mutiny cog belay blow the man down. Draught hornswaggle barkadeer jib interloper fore marooned sloop lad scurvy hardtack nipperkin grapple piracy take a caulk capstan lateen sail yard scuppers coxswain. 
  </p>
  <p class="para2">
   Handsomely clap of thunder flogging pillage Jack Tar wherry pirate plunder keel quarter red ensign hands draught league Shiver me timbers smartly swab fathom haul wind hail-shot. Bilge rat landlubber or just lubber crack Jennys tea cup rum wherry Buccaneer heave to spike bilge water avast red ensign piracy tack mutiny chase guns shrouds cackle fruit booty main sheet quarter. Barque six pounders scuttle shrouds bilged on her anchor tender rigging Admiral of the Black gabion spike Arr belay sloop me rope's end lee black spot weigh anchor yo-ho-ho holystone. Holystone overhaul walk the plank schooner to go on account swab yard parley boom plunder lateen sail ho draught tack deadlights gunwalls parrel smartly maroon dance the hempen jig. Dance the hempen jig Chain Shot Cat o'nine tails skysail code of conduct case shot Letter of Marque stern run a shot across the bow jolly boat booty jack six pounders pink barkadeer Nelsons folly mutiny Sink me belay heave to. 
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 If I do it this way do I then remove the onclick attribute from the HTML ???

Comment: @PeteSmyth Yes, inline onclick in html is not required.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.querySelector(".head-title");
    title.innerHTML += "<br>(or how to speak like a pirate)";
  };
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

header > h1 {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #A47F1A;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: dashed 5px #A47F1A;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #3B2E2A
}

 .nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3B2E2A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding: 20px 0 20px 0;*/
}

 .nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding: 0 25px;*/
}

 .nav li a {
  color: #FEF1E0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #FEF1E0;
  color: #3B2E2A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content > p {
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test JS Usage</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1 class="head-title">
   Pirate Verbal Diahorrea
  </h1>
  <nav>
   <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Title</button>
   <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Para1 colour</button>
   <button onclick="changeTitle();">Change Header Colour</button>
  </nav>
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Change Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Change Para1 colour</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Change Header Colour</a></li>
  </ul>
  
 </header>
 <div class="content">
  <p class="para1">
   Ahoy league cutlass Sail ho grapple brig cable Chain Shot topgallant rutters grog keel run a shot across the bow squiffy execution dock chandler ballast heave to come about weigh anchor. Bowsprit Yellow Jack lugsail warp gally piracy strike colors flogging come about avast fluke Sea Legs parrel black spot hempen halter run a shot across the bow American Main crow's nest red ensign cable. Gally jolly boat long clothes quarterdeck fluke league bilge water dance the hempen jig interloper jib scourge of the seven seas swab haul wind Chain Shot draught rope's end belay reef Yellow Jack Buccaneer. Nelsons folly topsail Cat o'nine tails hail-shot scuttle scourge of the seven seas loaded to the gunwalls carouser Sail ho fluke bowsprit lateen sail gabion yard provost hands mutiny cog belay blow the man down. Draught hornswaggle barkadeer jib interloper fore marooned sloop lad scurvy hardtack nipperkin grapple piracy take a caulk capstan lateen sail yard scuppers coxswain. 
  </p>
  <p class="para2">
   Handsomely clap of thunder flogging pillage Jack Tar wherry pirate plunder keel quarter red ensign hands draught league Shiver me timbers smartly swab fathom haul wind hail-shot. Bilge rat landlubber or just lubber crack Jennys tea cup rum wherry Buccaneer heave to spike bilge water avast red ensign piracy tack mutiny chase guns shrouds cackle fruit booty main sheet quarter. Barque six pounders scuttle shrouds bilged on her anchor tender rigging Admiral of the Black gabion spike Arr belay sloop me rope's end lee black spot weigh anchor yo-ho-ho holystone. Holystone overhaul walk the plank schooner to go on account swab yard parley boom plunder lateen sail ho draught tack deadlights gunwalls parrel smartly maroon dance the hempen jig. Dance the hempen jig Chain Shot Cat o'nine tails skysail code of conduct case shot Letter of Marque stern run a shot across the bow jolly boat booty jack six pounders pink barkadeer Nelsons folly mutiny Sink me belay heave to. 
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is asking for help in understanding why the problem occurred, such code only answers (though working), will not increase his understanding of why it happened

Comment: Please explain the problem and why your answer helps. We're here to educate people, not just dump code